# How do I get and set the Metadata Value for a block item in Minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm writing a Minecraft module using Minecraft Forge.

I can retrieve a Block object from the world, using

```
Block b = world.getBlock(x,y,z);
```

however, now that I have the block, how do I find out the metadata?  If the block is a StoneSteps block, then I want to know it's orientation, which is held in the metadata.

Similarly, how do I set this value?  I can create a new block simply enough:

```
Block b = Blocks.stone_stairs;
```

but again, how do I now set this block to a particular orientation?  I know you can do this when creating an ItemStack, but in this case, I want a Block object that can be passed on to `world.setBlock()`.

There does not appear to be any way I can find to get and set this value.

Comment: For the benefit of future viewers: this is a case where Forge 1.7 and Forge 1.8 differ markedly.  Under 1.7 you have `world.getBlock(int.int,int)` and `world.getBlockMetadata(int,int,int)`.  However under 1.8 you only have `world.getBlockState(BlockPos)`.  A 'state' is a new MC1.8 object that combines the block type, datavalue, and even aspects of the corresponding tile entity.  You then pull the DV out of the state; to set, you create a new  blockstate from the block type and metadata, then use that with `setBlockState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `world.getBlockState(BlockPos);` for Minecraft 1.8 or `getBlockMetadata(int x, int y, int z);` for Minecraft 1.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the block through:

```
yourBlock.rotateBlock(World someWorld, int x, int y, int z, ForgeDirection axis);
```

From the docs:

> Rotate the block. For vanilla blocks this rotates around the axis passed in (generally, it should be the "face" that was hit).
>   Note: for mod blocks, this is up to the block and modder to decide. It is not mandated that it be a rotation around the face, but could be a rotation to orient *to* that face, or a visiting of possible rotations.
>   The method should return true if the rotation was successful though.

Comment: This looks like most of what I need.  I assume it rotates the block in the world, rather than the metadata in the `yourBlock` object?  Also, although it specifies the axis around which to rotate, it doesn't seem to specify how far to rotate...
Also, this doesn't help with e.g. getting and setting the colour of a wool block, only with orientation

Comment: @SteveShipway Rotation of a block is not set by Metadata, which is volatile and is removed every reload, but damage values, which is exactly this problem. Use what this answer tells you and stop assuming.

Comment: It seems that I'm possibly using the wrong terminology.  The value I'm trying to get/set is the 4bit Damage Value, or maybe Data Value.  However it appears that the function `world.getBlockMetadata(x,y,z)` returns it, so maybe it's also called Metadata.  Documentation is not clear... this function returns the block orientation and the wool colour, which is what I was after, though the rotateBlock function is also very useful to find out about.